# How to turn off thumbnail previews in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, security, evince

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to tell Nautilus not to generate previews of PDF files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5828/is-there-a-way-to-tell-nautilus-not-to-generate-previews-of-pdf-files)

I would like to turn off automatic previews of PDF documents in Ubuntu.  Nautilus calls Evince PDF viewer to generate previews of PDF documents that can be displayed on the desktop and the file explorer.

There are vulnerabilities in Evince that can be exploited by malicious PDFs that would execute merely by viewing them in the file explorer.

How can you turn off automatic previews in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/5828/18612