# A: How to disable generation of thubmnail just for video / movie?

Tags: 12.04, video, filemanager, thumbnails

How to disable generation of thumbnails for video files in file browser?

---

Solved accordingly to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5828/is-there-a-way-to-tell-nautilus-not-to-generate-previews-of-pdf-files#answer-87055) answer.

1. Install `dconf-tools` package and run `dconf-editor`.
2. "In the tree on the left, navigate `org → gnome → desktop → thumbnailers`, then edit the `disable` option in the right pane as above."
3. I've typed value `['video/avi', 'video/mp4']` to the **disable** named field.

Works like a charm, video thumbnails (of provided mime types) are no longer generated in `nautilus`.

Comment: When you say an "annoying load" do you mean it takes a while to for Nautilus (the file manager) to display all the movie files, or that you are running out of space on the hard drive due to all the tumbnails?

Comment: I consider any 'load' (CPU load, HDD load) as a performance issue not a space issue.